# Converting RGB pixel values in the range [-1,1]

Tags: android, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I am not an `android` developer and I have very little knowledge how it works. I took a sample code from github where the person is reading the image data from the camera and converting the pixel values in the range `[0,1]`. The lines of code doing this operation are these :

```
imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.f);
imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.f);
imgData.putFloat((pixelValue & 0xFF) / 255.f);
```

Can someone please show me how to convert the pixel values in the range `[-`-1,1]`? Also, is there a way to read the pixel values by applying a breakpoint?

Comment: Why do you need colors in the range -1 to 1?

Comment: I am deploying a `machine learning model` that needs the color range in `[-1,1]` not in `[0,1]`

Comment: Then multiply by two and subtract one.

Comment: Are you saying like this `(((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF)*2.f / 255.f)-1.f)`?

Comment: divide by 128 and minus one e.g. `((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) / 128.f) - 1);`